# Find spaces and alphanumeric characters in a string

Tags: c, string, function, character

I need to develop a function that goes through a character string and detects letters (lower and upper cases), digits 0-9 and spaces ' '. If the functions finds only valid characters (the characters listed before) it returns 1 otherwise(if the string has characters like !,&,/,£, etc.) it returns 0. I am aware of a function that finds characters and digits which is isalnum().That is not helpful to find spaces. Does anyone can provide    inbuilt or manual function which can detect characters,digits and spaces all together. 
I've developed mine as under but function does not detect invalid character   !,&,/,£ etc. in middle of the string and therefore it does not return the value I expect.

```
for (i=0; i<strlen(str); i++) {
        if ((str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z') || str[i] == ' ' || (str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z') || (str[i]>='0' && str[i]<='9'))


for (i=0; i<strlen(str); i++) {
            char *p = str;
            while (*p) {
                if (isalnum((unsigned char) *p) || *p == ' ') {
                    res =1;
                } else {
                    res = 0;
                }
                    p++;
                }
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "but if I have an invalid character in between the string"? Can you be more clear about what the function should do and what isn't working?  It looks like your code is two partial snippets not complete and compiling. The first for loop looks about right, but there are pieces missing.

Comment: @Ander it is OK, I figured this out.. Now I will post the solution and reformulate the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the code more succinct:

```
int Validate_Alphanumeric(char *str)
{
    unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)str;
    unsigned char uc;

    while ((uc = *ptr++) != '\0')
    {
        if (!isalnum(uc) && uc != ' ')
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Amongst other things, this avoids reevaluating `strlen(str)` on each iteration of the loop; that nominally makes the algorithm quadratic as `strlen()` is an O(N) operation and you would do it N times, for O(N<sup>2</sup>) in total.  Either cache the result of `strlen(str)` in a variable or don't use it at all.  Using `strlen(str)` requires the entire string to be scanned; the code above will stop at the first punctuation or other verboten character without scanning the whole string (but the worst case performance, for valid strings, is O(N)).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a function that goes through the string and that is able to return 0 if an invalid character (ex. $&$&&(%$(=()/)&)/) is found.

```
int Validate_Alphanumeric (char str[]) {

    int i;
    int res;
    int valid=0;
    int invalid=0;


        const char *p = str;
        while (*p) {
            if (isalnum((unsigned char) *p) || *p == ' ') {
                valid++;
            } else {
                invalid++;
            }
                p++;
            }

        if (invalid==0)
            res=1;
        else
            res=0;

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Looks good. A couple nits: why do you cast *p to unsigned char in isalnum? The indentation is confusing: p++ and the } should be one tab left and the entire body is indented an extra step except for the variables and return. You also do not have to count valid or invalid - in fact you could simply `return 0` instead of `invalid++` and `return 1` instead of `return res` and remove three variables and the if/else. Anyhow, just pointers. Good job fixing it! Cheers!

Comment: Note that you never use `valid`; you may as well not increment it or define it.